# "ChallengeResponseAuthentication" is missing in Debian sshd_config

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I want to install 2FA for my Debian Server.. and now im at the Point for

```
Next, enter the following command to edit the sshd_config file.

sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Find the term ChallengeResponseAuthentication and set its value to yes. Also find the term PasswordAuthentication, uncomment it, and change its value to no.

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
```

but in my sshd_config isn't an line like PasswordAuthentication..

can anybody help me to solve this problem?

I followed this guide:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-setup-two-factor-authentication-2fa-for-ssh-on-debian-9-using-google-authenticator

Answer (score 0):

If those lines aren't in your `sshd_config` already, they'll be using the default values (which are `PasswordAuthentication yes` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes` by default, per the `sshd_config(5)` man page).

So all you need to do is add the line `PasswordAuthentication no` to the `sshd_config` file. That's it!

*Edit based on comments:* before setting `PasswordAuthentication no`, make sure you have **tested** an alternative method of logging in to the server (usually public key). If the alternative method isn't working and you don't have out-of-band access to the OS, **you could lock yourself out**.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WKGJSajg
so correct ?

Comment: That appears to be correct. As an aside, you probably want to change `PermitRootLogin` to `no` and use a utility like `sudo` or `su` as a normal user to gain root privileges when you need to.

Comment: ok now i get an error and cant login 
https://gyazo.com/9d275e3c22b5fd5e862cd62762712935

Comment: Since you just disabled password authentication, if you don't have a public key present on the client (Pageant) and server (usually in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`), you won't be able to log in. This is why the next step in the guide you're following says to add the line `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive`: the `keyboard-interactive` part will let you interact with the TOTP prompt. The guide you reference is poorly written: it doesn't warn users of potentially locking themselves out. Do you have out-of-band access to this server?

Comment: do u have discord ?